# Not able add combobox as edittor for a combobox cell GXT 3.1.2

Tags: gwt, combobox, gxt

I want to add a combobox in my grid, which would populate its store(of grid) as user provide the word.

If i am adding a custom abstract cell in to grid, I can able to add combobox as edittor to it. But when i am trying to use combobox cell (need to display text in a input tag/ Editable), Combobox is not adding to Grid.

Mean to say when I click on that column, it's not converting to combobox.

Tried with adding keyuphandler to addHandler method. But It's not coming to that handler.

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:cellgrid  ? There is quire clear example of ComboBox cell. Can you attach picture of you want to do?

Comment: Yes. I want to add a advanced combo box into my grid. So at the time of grid load, some textbox will apear. if user start typing, suggestions will be coming in dropdown.   i can able to achieve it, If i am showing some text on load of grid and textbox is apearing when user clicks on that text. But i wanna show textbox in load itself.   How can i do it?